# Build C++ unit tests for C89 code

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing

I'm hoping this won't turn to a dead end, but here's what I would like to do. Please let me know if this is even remotely possible, or if you have another good (or better) approach.

I'm working on a legacy code base that's C89 standard (what year is it again?) and I would like to build unit tests for some parts of the software. The C unit test frameworks I've found do not seem nearly as useful and easy as the [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) framework in C++, or really most other C++ unit test framework for obvious reasons. Thus, I would like to build these unit tests in C++.

There exists some homebrew build process that will build whatever application you're working on, all using the C89 standard. The system was built because there are a lot of shared dependencies among projects, and this was made before better alternatives existed. What I would like to do is use the artifacts built from that process to be linked in to a C++ unit test application. I could, alternatively, try to find all the dependencies and build them in to the unit test, but that's 1. redundant to rebuild, 2. cumbersome, and 3. removes the C89 compiledness of them, which I'd like to maintain to ensure the code I'm testing will be exactly as it runs for the end user (compiled in C89, not C++).

Using the same compiler (gcc), is this possible to accomplish, or am I stuck with C unit test frameworks? Some technical explanation either way would be very helpful, since I'm not too familiar with the differences among the different language and standard library artifacts (other than the library itself is different). Also, note that at this point changing the build process is (unfortunately) not feasible (read: in the budget).

Comment: In my view, it should be doable provided you have suitable headers for all the parts of the system that will be exploited by the C++ unit test code.  Those headers should be usable by the C++ compiler, and will need to be wrapped inside `extern "C" {` and a matching `}`.  This might be done inside the unit test code or in the main headers (based on `#if defined(__cplusplus)`).  If you don't have headers that can be compiled by C++, then it is not going to be possible until you do have appropriate headers.

Comment: Ah yes, some of it's coming back to me now. But can I link my C++ unit test executable directly with the C89 objects? No worries about potential conflicts using different versions of the standard library in the same application?

Comment: You might need to add `-lc` to the link line, but probably won't.  The C library will be the same as you used anyway — there isn't a separate C89 library and C99 library and C11 library.  So, although your code under test is written to C89 and your code testing it is in C++11, the C code will be using the current C library and test code will be using the C++ library.  The C++ code will be using facilities in the C++ `std` namespace, so you shouldn't run into any troubles there.  That said, I've not validated this, but it is the sort of thing that compilers get right.

Comment: Hmm, in a simple test case I was able to do exactly what I wanted (not importing the header with the extern, oddly enough. That gave undefined reference errors...). That was suspiciously easy to get working, so I'll give it a try tomorrow with a realistic example and report back any issues (hopefully none). I suppose I should have just tried before asking, but I assumed I'd be going down some ungodly rabbit hole...

Comment: Fortunately for you, no ungodly (or even godly) rabbit holes.  There's a book [Test Driven Development for Embedded C](https://pragprog.com/book/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c) which recommends C++ unit test frameworks for testing (embedded) C code.

Comment: Curious: I wonder why the C++ code was able to call the C functions under test (that were not name-mangled with C++ conventions) without a header of some sort declaring those functions.  It shouldn't work, I think — but it did.

Comment: Looking back I may have compiled my example C files with g++ which seems to mangle names even in .c files. Using gcc produced the expected results (requiring addition with extern "C" as expected). @JonathanLeffler

Comment: In my book, that means you have good quality code — if your C code can be compiled with a C++ compiler, it is pretty clean.  Congratulations.  Your explanation makes sense, though, of what would otherwise be a puzzling scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer*</sup>

In my view, it should be doable provided that you have suitable headers for all the parts of the system that will be exploited by the C++ unit test code. Those headers should be usable by the C++ compiler, and will need to be wrapped inside `extern "C" {` and a matching `}`. This might be done inside the unit test code or in the main (C) headers (based on `#if defined(__cplusplus)`). If you don't have headers that can be compiled by C++, then it is not going to be possible until you do have appropriate headers.

> Can I link my C++ unit test executable directly with the C89 objects? No worries about potential conflicts using different versions of the standard library in the same application?

You will be linking with the C++ compiler.  You might need to add `-lc` to the link line, but probably won't. The C library will be the same as you used anyway — there isn't a separate C89 library and C99 library and C11 library. So, although your code under test is written to C89 and your code testing it is in C++11, the C code will be using the current C library and test code will be using the C++ library. The C++ code will be using facilities in the C++ std namespace, so you shouldn't run into any troubles there. That said, I've not validated this, but it is the sort of thing that compilers get right.

There's a book [Test Driven Development for Embedded C](https://pragprog.com/book/jgade/test-driven-development-for-embedded-c) which recommends C++ unit test frameworks for testing (embedded) C code.

Answer (score 1):

Code is easily included in a C++ project simply by linking in your C object files (.o, .a). C header files are included in the C++ project wrapped with extern "C", e.g.

```
extern "C" {
#include "my_c_header.h"
}
```

You might get weird compile- and run-time issues. Look out for some C legacy code gotchas like #defining `bool` and replacing allocators with custom memory management schemes. -_-'